# What should I do if the creting a connection failed?

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error

I'm working on a web application using JMS and currently I have a bean with the following initializer method:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    try {
        connection.start();
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e); // <---------- Here
    }
}
```

The JMSException is a checked exception. Since, it's not possible for my application to recover if the connection cannot be started I throw `RuntimeException`. But I'm not sure about it. Maybe I should throw some `Error` instead in order to force `JVM` termination.

Comment: Normally what you want to do with exceptions that you can't recover from is to terminate that sequence and log when and if possible, why that exception was thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is upto you and your application design to report the JMSException as a checked `Exception` or `RuntimeException`.

In general, if you want to to expose an API in application to take an alternative action, then throw the CheckedException either without handling the `JMSException` or by handling and wrapping it with a `CustomException`.

As, you said if you do not have an alternative option in this case and expects the application to quit, you can throw a `RuntimeException` as you did. But I prefer defining a more meaningful extenstion of RuntimeException like `ConnectionFailedException` as given below.

```
public class ConnectionFailedException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7168847000818691293L;

    public ConnectionFailedException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public ConnectionFailedException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, sounds reasonable.